# How can I see the source code of Python builtin methods?

Tags: python, built-in

How can I see the `getattr` source code?

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        name = "a"

if __name__ == '__main__':

    a = A()
    print(getattr(a, 'name', 'nihao'))
```

in my PyCharm, I <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>click</kbd> the **getattr** builtin method, there jump to this file `/Users/xxx/Library/Caches/PyCharm2017.2/python_stubs/776880377/builtins.py`:

but there did not implement it:

```
def getattr(object, name, default=None): # known special case of getattr
    """
    getattr(object, name[, default]) -> value

    Get a named attribute from an object; getattr(x, 'y') is equivalent to x.y.
    When a default argument is given, it is returned when the attribute doesn't
    exist; without it, an exception is raised in that case.
    """
    pass
```

How can I see the source code of builtin methods?

Comment: @DyZ But whether the implement of builtin method source code I can see in my Mac?

Comment: It is not on your Mac. It is somewhere in the repositories (probably on GitHub).